# Integrating github imageshack SDK with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, imageshack

I am newbie for Github and Android. I want to use [imageshack sdk.](https://github.com/imageshack/imageshack-android-sdk) but I don't know how to use. There is no dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.imageshack:1.0.3'
}
```

Also, their getting started guide is for Eclipse not for Android Studio. 
So, sometimes integrating can be serious problem for me. 
 How can I integrate this SDK with my Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download imageshack SDK. Then you can try this method.

1. Open project structure in AndroidStudio and press '+' in top left corner("New module").
2. Import Eclipse ADT Project
3. Choose folder with ImageShackSDK, set name to module
4. Click next and finish
5. Sync gradle
6. Go again into projectStructure and select app module
7. Select dependecies tab
8. Click add("+" in right top corner) module dependency
9. Choose module and sync gradle again
10. Now u can try to use lib

Comment: Number 6 is problem for me.
Go again into projectStructure and select app module. 
Where to find app module?

Comment: @serkan
It's a default module. U can find it in the left column(Modules) in projectStructure

Comment: Yes I found, their properties are different. Does this give error? Compile sdk versions are different also build Tools are different. Remains are null

Comment: @serkanstack try to change build tools. I've added lib without problems. What version of build tools are you using?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIS you could create a library module in Android Studio for the sdk. (From the ImageShackSDK folder). 
After that you can reference the module in your own app.

Edit:
Here is a guide how to create a library project
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: How to do? I am newbie.